# How to add seconds to datetime of 'created' column

Tags: mysql, datetime, stored-procedures

How to add seconds to datetime of 'created' column each looping in MySql StoresProcedures.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertBulkData`()
BEGIN    
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;

    DECLARE id TEXT DEFAULT 1;    
    DECLARE created TEXT DEFAULT 1;
    
    
    # "29/01/2023 13:43:56"
    SET created = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%m:%s'); 
       
    WHILE counter <= 1000 DO
    
        SET id = LPAD(counter, 9, 0);       
            
        INSERT INTO `ctech_discount_card`.`customer`
        (`ID`,
        `created`)
        VALUES (
        id,
        created);

        SET counter = counter + 1;
        SET created = DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(CONVERT(created, DATE), "00:00:01"), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%m:%s'); // Problem in here
        
    END WHILE;

END
```

Thanks.

The result expected of 'created' column as follows:

Example:

```
29/01/2023 13:43:56
29/01/2023 13:43:57
29/01/2023 13:43:58
29/01/2023 13:43:59
29/01/2023 13:44:00
```

Comment: *How to add seconds to datetime of 'created' column* `SET created = created + INTERVAL 1 SECOND`

Comment: You use MySQL, but your SQL code syntax is SQL Server (MS SQL) -specific. Do not mix, these are two different DBMSs.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertBulkData`()
BEGIN    
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;

    DECLARE id        TEXT DEFAULT 1;    
    DECLARE created   DATE;
    DECLARE screated  TEXT DEFAULT "";
    
    
    # "29/01/2023 13:43:56"
    SET created = now();
       
    WHILE counter <= 1000 DO
    
        SET id = LPAD(counter, 9, 0);       

        SET screated = DATE_FORMAT(created, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s');
            
        INSERT INTO `ctech_discount_card`.`customer`
        (`ID`,
        `created`)
        VALUES (
        id,
        screated);

        SET counter = counter + 1;
        SET created = DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL 1 SECOND);
        
    END WHILE;

END
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).